# interface hunt for something like Appendable or OutputStream

Tags: java, interface, io

Hmmm. I'm trying to write a class that accepts bytes, and would like to implement a well-known interface for this purpose.

[`java.io.OutputStream`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) is an abstract class, not an interface (why???) and that makes me nervous, as I don't know what the consequences are of extending it. If there are no consequences, it should have been an interface. Otherwise it makes me think that it defines `equals()` and `hashCode()` or maybe one of the `Serializable`-related behaviors, and there's something I should know about before trying to extend it. Anyway if I do extend it, that means I've used up my 1 superclass and can't extend something else that's more vital to my application.

[`java.lang.Appendable`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Appendable.html) is an interface that does what I want, but for characters, not bytes.

[`java.nio.WritableByteChannel`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/channels/WritableByteChannel.html) is sort of what I want, and I might use it, but it only accepts ByteBuffers as inputs, not byte[] arrays.

Any other suggestions/advice? (p.s. is "input-output" the best tag for I/O questions?)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand why you're nervous about extending `OutputStream`. Could you elaborate? (I feel like a therapist!)

Comment: I agree. There's not that much going on in OutputStream. so  you should be fine ;]

Answer (score 1):

`java.io.DataOutput` might work for you, although it has many more methods than you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use a well-known interface?

There is no harm in creating your own interface for your purpose.

Besides, I wouldn't call `Appendable` or `WritableByteChannel` 'Well-known'.

Comment: Why? Because using a standard interface can reduce coupling between your application components.

Comment: How would a standard interface reduce coupling more than one of his own?

Comment: Because a standard interface may already be present in both components, and therefore wouldn't require a compile-time dependency between the two.

Comment: The idea of a 'standard' vs. 'non-standard' interface is not in Java.  I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: java.io.DataOutput is standard because it's part of the standard API.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problems extending java.io.OutputStream.  It is designed to be used as a base class.  If you are worried, take a look at the source code for OutputStream.

My only question is whether the OutputStream API matches your application requirements, or whether a different API might be more suitable.  Nobody will complain if you design your own interface that is more closely aligned to your application requirements.